# reinterpret_cast<int *>(char *)

Tags: c++, pointers, int

When dynamically allocating a buffer of type char * and when you want to cast it to a particular type, should you use:

```
reinterpret_cast<int *>(char *)
```

or:

```
static_cast<int *>(static_cast<void *>(char *))
```

and why?

Comment: Any good introductory C++ book will explain that. The first is a declaration of a pointer, the second dereferences the pointer. The `*` means different things in the two contexts.

Comment: Of course I know that.  Maybe you didn't understand my question or my question is poorly constructed.

Comment: -1: failure to do basic research.

Comment: My basic research shows multiple suggestions including on this site that this has to work: *pk = reinterpret_cast<int*>(2); and also this *pk = (int*) 2 but it obviously doesn't.

Comment: `pk` is a pointer.  `*pk` is an int *only* once you've given `pk` a valid value.  Til then, the behavior is undefined, but you'll generally end up with a segfault.

Answer (score 5):

This `*pk = new int(2);` should be `pk` instead of `*pk`

After you've declared a pointer `int * pointer`, all references to `point` refer to an address and all references to `*pointer` refer to what's contained at the address. By default, pointers don't point to valid memory locations, you have to assign a valid address or make a call to `new`. This is why when you write `pk = &k`, there is no segmentation faults - because `pk` now contains the address of `k`, which points to a valid memory location.

The syntax for pointers can be a little confusing, mainly because `*` can have multiple meanings, depending on how you use it. Here's a quick explanation:

- In declarations, `*` means you are declaring a pointer (ie `int * pk`).
- In between to numerical data types, `*` is the symbol for multiplication (ie `4 * num`).
- Written next to a variable, it returns the value at the address that the pointer contains (ie `*myPointer` or `(*mypointer)` ).

Since `new` returns an address, you are assigning an address to `pk` instead of a value pointed by `pk`.

If you wish to initialize a pointer, declare it with a `new` statement. Like this:

```
int * pk = new int;
```

But there is no compile time feature that declares a self-contained pointer and value. The closest you'll come to that is by declaring separate variable, as you have done, and initialize the pointer with the address of that variable. Like this:

```
int num = 43;
int * p = &num;
```

Comment: Exactly. pk is a pointer to an int; new int(...) returns a pointer to an int, *pk is an int.

Comment: I'm sorry! You are right. That's a mistake and not part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

- Can you explain me what's going on here?

You use unitialized variable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable

```
int* pk;  // declare variable `pk` of type `int*` but do not initialize it
*pk = 2;  // use unitialized variable. `*` is dereference operator. Seg fault
int k;    // declare variable `k` of type `int`, not initialized
pk = &k;  // initialize variable `pk` with address of variable `k`
*pk = 3;  // use initialized variable. Ok now
```

Dereference operator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator

Answer (score 0):

```
int* pk = nullptr;
```

Here you are declaring that pk is a pointer to an `int`.

```
*pk = new int(2);
```

The type of `*pk` is `int` and the return type of `new int(2)` is `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

`pk` is the pointer while `*pk` is the value to which it points.

So change your code to,

```
int* pk = new int;

pk = reinterpret_cast<int*>(2);
```

When assigning to `pk` the right-hand side must be a pointer, for `*pk` it must be an integer.

Comment: `*pk` is the *object* to which `pk` points, not just the value of that object.

Comment: When I dereference *pk I get a seg fault in that case;

Comment: @Zingam Well of course, you're assigning `x` to address `0x02`. You don't know what's at that address. That's what you get for using `reinterpret_cast`, it's implicitly dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I initialize a pointer with a value?

You don't. That's the *point* of having a pointer. You don't initialize it with value. You initialize it with variable *address*.

Let's analyze it step by step:

```
int* pk;
```

You have a pointer, and it's uninitialized, so now it's worse than useless.

```
int* pk = nullptr;
```

Much better, at least you can check with an `if` statement if it points to anything.

```
if(pk)
{
    //do operations on pointed value *pk
}
else
{
    //Houston, we have a problem
}
```

For now, these operations make no sense

```
*pk = 2; //you haven't pointed with pk to anything
*pk = reinterpret_cast<int*>(2); //????? *pk is int, and right-hand side is int*. What do you expect to do with it?
```

This code works

```
int k;
pk = &k;
*pk = 3;
```

because you actually pointed pk to something meaningful.